# Prove that $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+(x^3-1)^2-4\rangle$ is reduced

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals

I want to prove that $\Bbb Q[x,y]/\langle x^2+(y-1)^2-4,y-x^3\rangle$ is reduced. After some manipulation I have  $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^2+(x^3-1)^2-4\rangle$. And to prove that $\langle x^2+(x^3-1)^2-4\rangle$ is radical. A theorem says I need to prove that $x^2+(x^3-1)^2-4$ is irreducible, but so far I have not got an idea about proveing it.

I do know that to show an ideal is radical by looking at the intersection to see that it is tansversal or tangential. But it is called "geometric intuition"... So I need a rigorous proof about it.

Any ideas, please. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\Bbb K$ a field of characteristic $0$, a principal ideal $\langle f\rangle\subseteq\Bbb K[x]$ is radical if and only if $\operatorname{Res}(f,f')\ne0$, where $\operatorname{Res}$ is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant). Equivalently, if and only if $\operatorname{gcd}(f,f')=1$. The first one amounts to the calculation of the determinant of a $11\times 11$ [Sylvester matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix), the entries of which depend on the coefficients of the polynomial. The second one amounts to using Euclid's algorithm.

Notice that it is not true that $\Bbb K[x]/\langle f\rangle$ is reduced if *and only if* $f$ is irreducible. For instance, $\Bbb R[x]/\langle(x-1)(x-2)\rangle\cong\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, the nilradical of which is indeed $0$.